# How to refresh a scrollable page at the same scroll location when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a very long "admin" page where I update 3 databases on one page. It displays the entirety of all 3 tables and has the `<form>` of each below them that I use to update/add/delete rows.

Currently, if I am updating the 2nd or 3rd table, I have to scroll down to the middle/bottom of the page each time I adjust something. Is there a way to automatically scroll the page back down to the last place I had it.

one of my "submit" buttons looks like this:

```
<form name="UpdateMedRow" METHOD="post" ACTION="cgupdate.php">
.... //<tr> <td> in this section for the different items to update
<tr><input type="submit" value="Update" name="updateMedRow"/></tr><br/>
```

then it goes to cgupdate.php - does whatever function I tell it - in this case, `UPDATE` medRow, then uses a header to jump back to cgadmin.php

```
header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/cgadmin.php' ) ;
?>
```

Any suggestions on how I could get that `header` to load the same location on the cgadmin page, or am I doomed since I'm leaving the page and coming back?

Comment: Since your page is constructed dynamically with PHP -- you could possibly use an HTML bookmark. Assuming that you save the record at the top of your code, you can set a variable. Then during your output code, you check the variable and place an HTML bookmark wherever that record is written. You'll need the bookmark as part of your POST action as well (cgupdate.php#getback) for example. Just an idea maybe you hadn't thought of.

Comment: I can try and give it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intercept the form submit via Javascript, calculate `window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop` - cross-browser way of calculating the document's current offset, and modify the action parameter of the form to `cgupdate.php?offset=716` (eg if your document is scrolled 716px from the top).

```
var myforms = document.querySelectorAll('[action="cgupdate.php"]');

for(var i=0;i<myforms.length;i++)
    myforms[i].onsubmit = function(){
        var scrolled = parseInt(window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop);
        event.target.action = "cgupdate.php?offset="+scrolled;
    }
```

The above intercepts submission of all forms that will submit to `cgupdate.php` and passes it a parameter which rounds out the value of the current offset to integer (otherwise values can sometimes end up like 72.44444).

Then inside `cgupdate.php` access this $_GET variable and pass it back to the URL like:

```
$scrolled = $_GET["offset"];
header('Location: http://www.jpegchaos.com/cgadmin.php?scroll='.$scrolled);
```

At the bottom of the `cgadmin.php` page, add code that gets this parameter ([how to get URL parameters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)) and scrolls your window to that number, which is simple:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var scrollTo = getParameterByName('scroll');
if(scrollTo) document.body.scrollTop = parseInt(scrollTo);
```

`parseInt` is used again because the parameter value is always a string while `scrollTop` accepts a number. It should work but I have not tested it, so I'd be interested to know if you run into any problems with this approach.

Comment: Sorry, this is going to take me some time. I'm not great with JS so I'm trying to make sure I add everything correctly.

Comment: the `$scrolled = $_GET("offset");` is giving me an error when I try and compile it in my IDE. I can't copy it so here is the best reiteration I can provide **Function name must be callable - a string, Closure or class implementing __invoke , current array**  I found some things online that says this may just be an error with phpStorm. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: try $_GET["offset"] -- I think that's a typo.

Comment: when I run the site it gives the following **Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/jpegchaos/public_html/cgupdate.php on line 174** which is the `$scrolled = $_GET("offset")` line